# Arrangements of the word COMBINATION not containing CAN, BIN, NIB

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways can we arrange the letters of the word **COMBINATION**, containing none of the patterns **CAN**, **BIN** and **NIB**?

Without restrictions, arranging the 11 letters with 2 **O**'s, 2 **I**'s and 2 **N**'s is $\frac{11!}{2!2!2!} $ ways.

Where I'm stuck at now is how to calculate the arrangements with CAN, NIB and BIN, since there are 2 **I**'s and 2 **N**'s, and also each of the patterns contain letters in the other pattern.

Can anyone could help me out with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an application of the inclusion exclusion principle. We use the above to write properties $P_1, P_2$ and $P_3$ respectively as

$P_1$ - Pattern CAN occurs

$P_2$ - Pattern BIN occurs

$P_3$ - Pattern NIB occurs

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3$ be the sets conforming to each property. Now using the above stated principle we know that

$$|\bar{A_1}\cap\bar{A_2}\cap\bar{A_3}| = |S| - \sum_{i=1}^3|A_i| +\sum_{i,j}|A_i \cap A_j| - |A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|$$

$A_1$ - Treat CAN as one entity and calculate the permutations of the entities (CAN),O,M,B,I,T,I,O,N which is equal to

$$|A_1| = \frac{9!}{2!}$$

$A_2$ - Treat BIN as one entity and calculate the permutations of the entities C,O,M,(BIN),A,T,I,O,N which is equal to

$$|A_2| = \frac{9!}{2!}$$

$A_3$ - Treat NIB as one entity and calculate the permutations of the entities C,O,M,(NIB),A,T,I,O,N which is equal to

$$|A_3| = \frac{9!}{2!}$$

$A_1\cap A_2$ - Putting CAN and BIN together and calculating the permutations of the entities (CAN),(BIN),O,M,I,O,T which is equal

$$|A_1\cap A_2| = \frac{7!}{2!}$$

$A_2\cap A_3$ - We cannot have BIN and NIB together as there's only one B in COMBINATION
$$|A_1\cap A_3| = 0$$

So, also $|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3| = 0$

**EDIT** - As was suggested by the commenter, there's one extra case that I forgot to account for, which is CANIB. This will be a part of $A_1\cap A_3$ and is calculated by the number of permutations of (CANIB),O,O,T,I,N,M

$$|A_1\cap A_3| = \frac{7!}{2!} + \frac{7!}{2!}$$

Hence the total number of combinations become

$$|\bar{A_1}\cap\bar{A_2}\cap\bar{A_3}| = \frac{11!}{2!2!2!} - 3\cdot\frac{9!}{2!} + 3\cdot\frac{7!}{2!}$$

Comment: You overlooked the case CANIB.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit my answer to reflect that